# Delete consecutive elements in array

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array with sorted integers. I want to delete consecutive numbers within the array. Example:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([1,2,3,6,9,13,14,15,20,25])

Expected output:
[3,6,9,13,15,20,25]
```

Comment: What is the rule for the first `1`?

Comment: Delete the first value (here: 1) if it is part of the sequence. Otherwise, keep it.

Comment: Why do you keep 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
mask_array = np.diff(array, append=False)==1 #
if len(mask_array)>1: 
    mask_array[-1] = mask_array[-2]
array[~mask_array]
```

Output:

```
array([ 3,  6,  9, 15, 20, 25])
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected output you give is a little ambiguous, why is 13 included but 1 not?

Anyway, a solution that comes close to what you want is:

```
output = array[0:-1][array[1:]-array[0:-1] != 1]
```

Comment: `array[1:]-array[0:-1] == np.diff(array)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
def filter(array):
    new_array = []
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        if array[i+1] - array[i] != 1:
            new_array.append(array[i])
    if array[-1] - array[-2] != 1:
        new_array.append(array[-1])
    return new_array
```